# Why is multiple if or conditions not being recognized?

Tags: javascript

The following works:

```
key = ['_id', 'something', 'joe', 'latitude', 'longitude']
```

let's assume we loop through the key:

```
if(key != 'longitude') {
// to ahead and execute if key is NOT longitude }
```

However I have three conditions I have to look for so I tried this:

```
    if(key != '_id' || key != 'latitude' || key != 'longitude') {
// I don't want you to execute if you're '_id', 'latitude' or 'longitude'
    }
```

The second one is not recognized.  It allows _id, latitude, longitude to be executed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `key` is "_id", then it is *not* "latitude" and it is also not "longitude".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND), because **all** condition have to be `true`.

```
if (key != '_id' && key != 'latitude' && key != 'longitude') {
```

A shorter approach would be [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
if (!['_id', 'latitude', 'longitude'].includes(key)) {
```

Comment: For the readability I would use `<array>.includes()` method. ```const keys = ['_id', 'latitude', 'longitude'] if(keys.include(key)) // actions```

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: it is because of not equal.

Answer (score 0):

So the i would suggest you go look at logic gates cause they help with boolean logic in programming..
To your question.
In the second case lets say the value is _id key!="latitude" will return true. 
So like Nina said you would have to use and (&&) and not or (||) so that the if statement is true when all 3 cases are met